CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=10.5.3700.0
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer,
Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.


Try to add CrystalDecision.ReportSource and set Copy Local to true


Sorry dear, but still got below error.                                                                                        Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.




